# Parse last item XML PHP using xpath (Russian Post tracking API)

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have some difficult parsing the last element (ns3:Name and 
ns3:OperDate) from Russian post tracking API using PHP.

Tried a few xpath queries without success.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is example of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <S:Body>
      <ns7:getOperationHistoryResponse xmlns:ns7="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory" xmlns:ns2="http://russianpost.org/sms-info/data" xmlns:ns3="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory/data" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns5="http://www.russianpost.org/custom-duty-info/data" xmlns:ns6="http://www.russianpost.org/RTM/DataExchangeESPP/Data">
         <ns3:OperationHistoryData>
            <ns3:historyRecord>
               <ns3:AddressParameters>
                  <ns3:OperationAddress>
                     <ns3:Index>102976</ns3:Index>
                     <ns3:Description>MR LC Vnukovo Cex-1</ns3:Description>
                  </ns3:OperationAddress>
                  <ns3:CountryFrom>
                     <ns3:Id>643</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Code2A>RU</ns3:Code2A>
                     <ns3:Code3A>RUS</ns3:Code3A>
                     <ns3:NameRU>?????????? ?????????</ns3:NameRU>
                     <ns3:NameEN>Russian Federation</ns3:NameEN>
                  </ns3:CountryFrom>
                  <ns3:CountryOper>
                     <ns3:Id>643</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Code2A>RU</ns3:Code2A>
                     <ns3:Code3A>RUS</ns3:Code3A>
                     <ns3:NameRU>?????????? ?????????</ns3:NameRU>
                     <ns3:NameEN>Russian Federation</ns3:NameEN>
                  </ns3:CountryOper>
               </ns3:AddressParameters>
               <ns3:FinanceParameters>
                  <ns3:Payment>0</ns3:Payment>
                  <ns3:Value>0</ns3:Value>
                  <ns3:MassRate>0</ns3:MassRate>
                  <ns3:InsrRate>0</ns3:InsrRate>
                  <ns3:AirRate>0</ns3:AirRate>
                  <ns3:Rate>0</ns3:Rate>
                  <ns3:CustomDuty>0</ns3:CustomDuty>
               </ns3:FinanceParameters>
               <ns3:ItemParameters>
                  <ns3:Barcode>RB842972220RU</ns3:Barcode>
                  <ns3:ValidRuType>false</ns3:ValidRuType>
                  <ns3:ValidEnType>false</ns3:ValidEnType>
                  <ns3:ComplexItemName>Small packet registered</ns3:ComplexItemName>
                  <ns3:MailType>
                     <ns3:Id>5</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Name>Small packet</ns3:Name>
                  </ns3:MailType>
                  <ns3:MailCtg>
                     <ns3:Id>1</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Name>Registered</ns3:Name>
                  </ns3:MailCtg>
                  <ns3:Mass>0</ns3:Mass>
               </ns3:ItemParameters>
               <ns3:OperationParameters>
                  <ns3:OperType>
                     <ns3:Id>8</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Name>Processing</ns3:Name>
                  </ns3:OperType>
                  <ns3:OperAttr>
                     <ns3:Id>0</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Name>Sorting</ns3:Name>
                  </ns3:OperAttr>
                  <ns3:OperDate>2016-12-20T22:56:13.000+03:00</ns3:OperDate>
               </ns3:OperationParameters>
               <ns3:UserParameters>
                  <ns3:SendCtg>
                     <ns3:Id>0</ns3:Id>
                  </ns3:SendCtg>
                  <ns3:Sndr>KAREPANOV</ns3:Sndr>
                  <ns3:Rcpn>PRONOVOST</ns3:Rcpn>
               </ns3:UserParameters>
            </ns3:historyRecord>
            <ns3:historyRecord>
               <ns3:AddressParameters>
                  <ns3:OperationAddress>
                     <ns3:Index>102972</ns3:Index>
                     <ns3:Description>MR LC Vnukovo MMPO Cex-2</ns3:Description>
                  </ns3:OperationAddress>
                  <ns3:MailDirect>
                     <ns3:Id>840</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Code2A>US</ns3:Code2A>
                     <ns3:Code3A>USA</ns3:Code3A>
                     <ns3:NameRU>??????????? ????? ???????</ns3:NameRU>
                     <ns3:NameEN>United States</ns3:NameEN>
                  </ns3:MailDirect>
                  <ns3:CountryFrom>
                     <ns3:Id>643</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Code2A>RU</ns3:Code2A>
                     <ns3:Code3A>RUS</ns3:Code3A>
                     <ns3:NameRU>?????????? ?????????</ns3:NameRU>
                     <ns3:NameEN>Russian Federation</ns3:NameEN>
                  </ns3:CountryFrom>
                  <ns3:CountryOper>
                     <ns3:Id>643</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Code2A>RU</ns3:Code2A>
                     <ns3:Code3A>RUS</ns3:Code3A>
                     <ns3:NameRU>?????????? ?????????</ns3:NameRU>
                     <ns3:NameEN>Russian Federation</ns3:NameEN>
                  </ns3:CountryOper>
               </ns3:AddressParameters>
               <ns3:FinanceParameters>
                  <ns3:Payment>0</ns3:Payment>
                  <ns3:Value>0</ns3:Value>
                  <ns3:MassRate>0</ns3:MassRate>
                  <ns3:InsrRate>0</ns3:InsrRate>
                  <ns3:AirRate>0</ns3:AirRate>
                  <ns3:Rate>0</ns3:Rate>
                  <ns3:CustomDuty>0</ns3:CustomDuty>
               </ns3:FinanceParameters>
               <ns3:ItemParameters>
                  <ns3:Barcode>RB842972220RU</ns3:Barcode>
                  <ns3:Internum>RB842972220RU</ns3:Internum>
                  <ns3:ValidRuType>false</ns3:ValidRuType>
                  <ns3:ValidEnType>false</ns3:ValidEnType>
                  <ns3:ComplexItemName>Small packet registered</ns3:ComplexItemName>
                  <ns3:MailRank>
                     <ns3:Id>0</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Name>Without rank</ns3:Name>
                  </ns3:MailRank>
                  <ns3:PostMark>
                     <ns3:Id>0</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Name>Without mark</ns3:Name>
                  </ns3:PostMark>
                  <ns3:MailType>
                     <ns3:Id>5</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Name>Small packet</ns3:Name>
                  </ns3:MailType>
                  <ns3:MailCtg>
                     <ns3:Id>1</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Name>Registered</ns3:Name>
                  </ns3:MailCtg>
                  <ns3:Mass>1700</ns3:Mass>
               </ns3:ItemParameters>
               <ns3:OperationParameters>
                  <ns3:OperType>
                     <ns3:Id>10</ns3:Id>
                     <ns3:Name>Export of international mail</ns3:Name>
                  </ns3:OperType>
                  <ns3:OperAttr>
                     <ns3:Id>0</ns3:Id>
                  </ns3:OperAttr>
                  <ns3:OperDate>2017-01-03T20:48:24.000+03:00</ns3:OperDate>
               </ns3:OperationParameters>
               <ns3:UserParameters>
                  <ns3:SendCtg>
                     <ns3:Id>0</ns3:Id>
                  </ns3:SendCtg>
                  <ns3:Sndr>KAREPANOV</ns3:Sndr>
                  <ns3:Rcpn>PRONOVOST</ns3:Rcpn>
               </ns3:UserParameters>
            </ns3:historyRecord>
         </ns3:OperationHistoryData>
      </ns7:getOperationHistoryResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: What have you tired and why are you not using the soap extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`last()`-test](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) on node sets:

> para[last()] selects the last para child of the context node

Concerning your question this would look as follows.

```xml
(//ns3:Name)[last()] | (//ns3:OperDate)[last()]
```

when applied to your sample xml, this expression yields the following result:

```xml
<ns3:Name>Export of international mail</ns3:Name>
<ns3:OperDate>2017:01:03T20:48:24.000+03:00</ns3:OperDate>
```